# Characteristics of wave equation on compactified coordinates

Tags: wave-equation, characteristics, compactification

I am following Zenginoglu's paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3809) on page 6-7. I am confused why my attempts to apply hyperboloidal compactification on the characteristics do not agree with the illustration Zenginoglu provided. I think I may have made a mistake when applying the transformation.

To provide some background: the characteristics of the standard wave equation
$$
\partial_t^2u - \partial_x^2u = 0
$$
are $x\pm t=c$ for some constant $c$. By applying the hyperboloidal compactification
$$
\begin{split}
\rho &= \dfrac{x}{1+x}\\
\tau &= t - h(x)
\end{split}
$$
where $h(x) = \sqrt{S^2 + x^2}$ is the height function (for consistency and computational purposes, set $S=10$), we transform the characteristics in the compactified $\rho/\tau$ coordinates as follows.

[image: transformation of characteristics]

I want to verify this claim computationally. Rewriting the characteristics $x\pm t = c$ with the parametrized function
$$
r_\pm(t) = (c\mp t, t)
$$
and defining the compactified parametrization of the characteristic as
$$
\bar{r}_\pm(t) = (\rho, \tau) = \bigg(\dfrac{x_\pm}{1 + x_\pm}, t - h(x_\pm)\bigg)
$$
we get
$$
\bar{r}_\pm(t) = \bigg(\dfrac{c\mp t}{1 + c\mp t}, t - \sqrt{S^2 + (c\mp t)^2}\bigg).
$$
However when I plot one line for $t\in(-100, 100)$ out I get a big mess, and it's not even in the right quadrant. Did I make a mistake with my transformation?

[image: big mess]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your $\rho$ is correct. In the article $x = \rho / \Omega$ (see equation (12)) where $\Omega = \Omega(\rho)$ where the zero set corresponds to spatial infinity. What you set above will have $\Omega = (1-\rho)$ which vanishes at $\rho = 1$, so necessarily you have a different picture from what he has. The correct $\Omega$ to use is given in equation (19) of the paper which takes the form

$$ \Omega = \frac12 \left( 1 - \frac{\rho^2}{S^2} \right) $$

where $S$ is a parameter showing how wide the compactified domain should be. In the shown picture, it was chosen with $S = 10$.